# Firebase server keys via Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, kotlin, authentication

I have a problem with Firebase project's server keys Android Studio. The instruction is

> The new service account's public/private key pair is automatically saved on your computer. Copy this file to your authentication server

The question is, how do I find my authentication server file?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to use the Firebase Admin SDK in an Android app, which is not supported. The Admin SDKs have full administrative access to your entire Firebase/GCP project and should only be used in trusted environments, such as your development machine, a server you control, or Cloud Functions.